# Plotting an Hourly Time Series in the Correct Order with Plotly in Python

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I'm trying to plot a timeseries graph and everything is working so far except for the time. For some reason plotly is plotting first days and afterwards it is starting with a different time and for the same period. Normally Plotly should recognise my time format. Does anyone know why it is not working properly?

This is my code:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

x = ['2017-01-01 00:00:00','2017-01-02 06:00:00','2017-01-03 12:00:00','2017-01-04 18:00:00','2017-01-05 00:00:00',
 '2017-01-06 06:00:00','2017-01-07 12:00:00','2017-01-08 18:00:00','2017-01-09 00:00:00','2017-01-10 06:00:00',
  '2017-01-01 12:00:00','2017-01-02 18:00:00','2017-01-03 00:00:00','2017-01-04 06:00:00','2017-01-05 12:00:00',
 '2017-01-06 18:00:00','2017-01-07 00:00:00','2017-01-08 06:00:00','2017-01-09 12:00:00','2017-01-10 18:00:00',
  '2017-01-01 00:00:00','2017-01-02 06:00:00','2017-01-03 12:00:00','2017-01-04 18:00:00','2017-01-05 00:00:00',
 '2017-01-06 06:00:00','2017-01-07 12:00:00','2017-01-08 18:00:00','2017-01-09 00:00:00','2017-01-10 06:00:00',
  '2017-01-01 12:00:00','2017-01-02 18:00:00','2017-01-03 00:00:00','2017-01-04 06:00:00','2017-01-05 12:00:00',
 '2017-01-06 18:00:00','2017-01-07 00:00:00','2017-01-08 06:00:00','2017-01-09 12:00:00','2017-01-10 18:00:00']

y1 = np.random.uniform(low=14, high=19.5, size=(40,))
y2 = np.random.uniform(low=14, high=25.0, size=(40,))

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y1,
    name = "Temperature LED",
    line = dict(color = '#17BECF'),
    opacity = 0.8)

trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y2,
    name = "Temperature MDL",
    line = dict(color = '#7F7F7F'),
    opacity = 0.8)

data = [trace1,trace2]

layout = dict(
    title='Temperature LED vs MDL',
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label='1d',
                     step='day',
                     stepmode='backward'),
                dict(count=6,
                     label='6d',
                     step='day',
                     stepmode='backward'),
                dict(step='all')
            ])
        ),
    rangeslider=dict(),
    type='date'
    )
)

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

py.plot(fig, filename="Time Series with Rangeslider")
```

This is the result:
[image: Plotly Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plotly does not reorder the `x` values of your traces before plotting them, and so plotting them out of sequence results in lines that jump back and forth. Sorting your x values (in this case, you can sort in place by just calling `x.sort()`) before creating your traces fixes the problem:

[image]

Note that all of the vertical lines in this plot are the result of all of the times in your `x` list being included twice (I'm not sure if this was intentional).

Comment: Thank you that will do the trick. But you probably mean eather `x.sort()` or `sorted(x)`. And no i did not want to have multiple x's.

Comment: You're welcome, and you are correct, I will fix that in my answer